# Improving pandas performance dealing with subsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance

Hope everybody is doing just fine during this tough moment.

I have a question, if someone could help me with.

I have the following code that is done with Pandas to test if a Dataframe has enough data to start calculations:

```
def testa_liga(dados,data,liga,minimo_jogos):

    criterio = (dados["liga"] == liga) & (dados["data"] < data)
    dados = dados[criterio]
    dados = dados.sort_values(by=["data"],ascending=False)
    quantidade = len(dados.index)

    if quantidade >= minimo_jogos:

        minimo = True

    else:

        minimo = False

    return minimo
```

Not only this but I do this kind of operations for a lot of other validations.

So my question is: is there any way to make it faster?

Pandas is turning out to be so slow that I'm considering using lists for the task.

Thanks!

Edit:

My dataframe looks like this:

```
   liga       data         home      away    p1  p2  oddh  oddd   odda  
0  SP1     2007-11-03     Mallorca  Valencia  0   2  2.65  3.32   2.85 
..................
```

Comment: You seems to work with strings and pandas is actually pretty slow to compute strings. Why do you call `sort_values`? It seems to not be useful because `len(dados.index)` should be the same after the sort and `dados` is not used after that.

Comment: Another question: are the other validations done on the same dataframe?

Comment: Please define the ambiguous *slow* and the dimensions (`shape`) and types (`dtypes`) of data.

Answer (score 0):

Used a custom function to achieve the same calculations and filtering.

It seems to be a much, much more efficient way to solve large calculations.